# Linux tty in guest virtual machine for windows 7

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I was unable to find any similar thread.

Cygwin is not compatible with some bash/make commands.
And I'm searching for a native Cygwin analogue for windows 7 with these features:

- tty only mode (for performance)
- root auto login to tty.
- Shared bidirectional clipboard.
- Internet access.
- Shared dirs

Does it exists? Or maybe there are similar solutions?

I already tried Ubuntu server tty in VirtualBox with disabled GUI for windows 7 host. But there were not simple solutions to auto login into tty1, only into next tty (2,3,4 etc). Clipboard did not worked as well.

Comment: Windows 10 now offers a Unbuntu bash shell on Windows: http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Comment: My colleagues have difficulties with the installation of software. Bash is not available for them right now in windows 10.Maybe later these will be fixed my Microsoft.